# What can I do when the AWS IoT Button runs out of charge?

Tags: batteries, amazon-iot-button

The [AWS IoT Button](https://aws.amazon.com/iotbutton/) ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01C7WE5WM)) is intriguing, but I saw something quite concerning in [the FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/iotbutton/faq/):

> **How long will the battery last?**
>
> The battery should last for approximately 1,000 presses. When the device battery runs out of charge, there is no way to recharge or replace the battery.

The battery life is reasonable, but what am I supposed to do when the battery runs out? For a $20 button (which is already expensive!), it seems odd that there is no solution when the battery dies.

**Does Amazon want you to throw away the old device and replace it when the batteries are out of charge?** Is it replaceable in any way, or is the battery permanently connected to the device in a way that it's impossible to replace?

Comment: Hmm, sounds like built in obsolescence.  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I read on [Matthew Petroff's teardown](https://mpetroff.net/2016/07/new-amazon-dash-button-teardown-jk29lp/), the battery could *sort-of* be replaceable.  In the new version of the AWS button, a triple A battery is in place, but you have to pry open the case manually, causing damage to the case. The reason they say the battery is not replaceable is because the plastic is welded together with an ultrasonic welder.  Therefore, it would be impossible to get the button back together in its original state with a new battery.

However, if you are a fairly resourceful person and don't mind your things looking a bit mangled, you could break or cut the plastic, fit a new battery, and tape or hot-glue it back together.  Not a real solution, but a work-around.

Apart from that, the only solution is to go with an alternative like the [IFTTT Do Button](https://ifttt.com/do_button) on your phone.

Comment: Not the only alternative - there's https://flic.io/ as well, which does have a changeable battery. Though it's Bluetooth, not WiFi.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like that is what Amazon intended. Since you are being credited for the purchase of the device, it is no loss to you and only to Amazon and the Earth itself (waste and whatnot)

However, there is a new model coming out on Friday, February 3 which will last twice as long as the original.